# CR-like-Theorem for powers of same prime

Tags: soft-question, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

CRT asks the numbers in denominator to be coprime, is there are theorem/property when taking modulo by powers of a prime? It's easy if the power is small but it gets tougher as the number and/or powers grows.

Or is there a way to quickly find modulo , with the help of some related property?
For example, $675453 \equiv 3 \pmod 5$ and $675453 \equiv 3 \pmod {25}$ but $675453 \equiv 78 \pmod {125}$

Is there some relationship between modulo of powers of prime?

Comment: Do you have an example to clarify your question?  Are you just asking for $$x \equiv a_i \pmod{p^i}$$ for some finite set of $i$? (i.e. different powers of a fixed prime)

Comment: @Brian Moehring, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. An easy counterexample try to find some $x$ such that $x \equiv 1 \mod 2$ and $x \equiv 2 \mod 4$.

The deeper reason for this is that we may state the CRT as

> Let $q_1, ..., q_n$ be coprime, then
> \begin{equation*}
> \mathbb{Z}/ \left(\prod_{i=1}^n q_i \right) \cong \prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{Z}/(q_i)
> \end{equation*}

However the same is not true when the $q_i$ are not coprime since $\mathbb{Z}/(p^n)$ is cyclic while $\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is not.

Fortunately it is not difficult to find $a \mod p^n$.

Comment: How to find it then?

Comment: @AshWhole in the same way you would compute $a \mod n$ for any $n$ - by dividing and finding the remainder. One might use long division by hand. If you want to know how computers do it fast, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm.

Comment: Okay.. I was hoping there maybe some shortcut